# How to return vertical size of an Excel File

Tags: vba, excel

I've this **excel file** with normal data. I want to know if there's is a way to know how many rows contains values using a **macro with VB code**.

[image]

Comment: this post may be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920

Comment: Do you wish to exclude any rows in the middle that do not contain data??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent no Gary I just want to know the size. I mean until which row that data is being populated

Comment: @pnuts just the last occupied row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your Comment:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim nLastRow As Long
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
    MsgBox nLastRow
End Sub
```